# Nodejs page freezes after multple requests to Custom API

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, pug

The problem I have is that my application works when I submit only one 1 when I press the Submit button multiple times it freezes and after some time (about 1000.000 ms) it returns the last request in the console and jade page. The submit button returns a post from the form and sends it to the same page . What the button also does is Refreshing the page. It is important that the page returns the (JSON) post to the page and there is an other json request that sends it to the API(and returns it to the same page )

app.js

```
var options_search = {
    hostname: 'host',
    path: 'path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': JSON request .length,
    }
};

app.post('/result',function(req,response){

    var keyword=req.body.user;


    GLOBAL.objToJson ={ keyword };
    response.write(JSON.stringify(GLOBAL.objToJson));

    console.log("test " +JSON.stringify(GLOBAL.objToJson) );

});



app.get('/Search', function(req, res) {

    var req = http.request(options_search,  (resb) => {

        var buffer_search = "";
        resb.setEncoding('utf8');

        resb.on('data', (chunks) => {
            buffer_search += chunks;
        });
        resb.on('end', () => {

            res.render('Search',{
                title: 'Search',
                value_search: buffer_search,
                search_test: [JSON.stringify(GLOBAL.objToJson) ]
            });
        });
       });

    //res.redirect("/search");
    req.write(search);

});
```

search.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
    script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var user,pass;
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                user=$("#user").val();
                pass=$("#password").val();
                $.post("http://localhost:3000/result",{user: user}, function(data){
                    if(data==='done')
                    {
                        alert("login success");
                    }

                });


            });
        });


        input#user(type='TEXT', size='40')
        br
        input#submit(type='button', value='Submit',onclick="location.href='search'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `result` route you are using the underlying HTTP [`.write()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) method to respond to the client. However this does not end the connection, which will stay open expecting more things to be written to the client.

If you are sending a string you should use [`.send()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) as that will write the string to the HTTP stream and end the response.

You may also want to consider not stringifying the object to a JSON string and just using [`.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) instead. So the line of code

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(GLOBAL.objToJson));
```

becomes

```
response.json(GLOBAL.objToJson);
```

Comment: Why should I consider that are there any differences between those?

Comment: If you don't end the response (either by calling `response.end()` after a call to `write()`, or by using `.send()` or `.json()` or any other function that ends the response for you) then the connection will stay open and not complete. Eventually express will time out, but in the mean-time you have an open connection that the client is waiting for to complete.